# Dynamics CRM2016: cannot read property 'SetParameter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016, subgrid

I've subgrid on Account form, I am trying to get list of Orders of child contact and then add to subgrid. So, far I did the following scripts but it throws error that **cannot read property 'SetParameter' of undefined**. Can anyone please guide how can I change fetchxml of a subgrid?

```
function listOfOrders(contactId){
    var orderFetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"+
                    "  <entity name='salesorder'>"+
                    "    <attribute name='name' />"+
                    "    <attribute name='customerid' />"+
                    "    <attribute name='salesorderid' />"+
                    "    <attribute name='statecode' />"+
                    "    <attribute name='createdon' />"+
                    "    <order attribute='name' descending='false' />"+
                    "    <filter type='and'>"+
                    "      <condition attribute='customerid' operator='eq' uitype='contact' value='"+contactId+"' />"+
                    "    </filter>"+
                    "  </entity>"+
                    "</fetch>";

    var retrievedOrders = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(orderFetchXml);

        var contactId = "";
        if(retrievedOrders.length <0)
            return;

    var viewId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var viewDisName = "Account Orders subgridview";

     var layOutXml = "<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='name' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'>" +
                            "<row name='result' id='salesorderid'>" +
                            "<cell name='name' width='300' />" +
                            "<cell name='statecode' />"+
                            "<cell name='createdon' />"+
                            "<cell name='customerid' />"+   
                            "disableSorting='1' />" +
                            "</row>" +
                    "</grid>";
    var orderSubgrid = window.parent.document.getElementById("orderssubgrid");
    //apply layout and filtered fetchXML
    orderSubgrid.control.SetParameter("layoutXml", layOutXml);
    orderSubgrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", orderFetchXml);
    //Refresh grid to show filtered records only. 
    orderSubgrid.control.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: When that script runs there is nothing in the DOM with the ID of `orderssubgrid`.  I'd start there.

Comment: what should I do, timeout?

Comment: Which contact are you basing the view on ? Is it from a lookup field on the Account ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a supported no-code way to do this.

- Create a QuickView in Contact entity containing the subgrid to Orders
- Add the QuickView to the Account entity linking it to the Contact lookup

If the Contact is not from a lookup, you can

- Add a hidden lookup on Contact in the Account form
- Make your javascript fill this lookup with the reference to the contact you want to filter the subgrid on (remember to `.fireOnChange()` after filling the field, to invoke the next step)
- invoke `refresh()` to update the subgrid in the onchange of the contact lookup you just filled

Then implement the quickview like the two points above.

Comment: thanks Alex, but I need subgrid of all orders, ordered by all contacts of an account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use a timeout. The code would look like:

```
function listOfOrders(contactId) {
    var orderSubgrid = window.parent.document.getElementById("orderssubgrid");
    if (orderSubgrid == null) {
        setTimeout(function () { listofOrders(contactId); }, 2000);
        return;
    }
    // ... the rest of your code
}
```

If you wanted to try a supported method there were new subgrid methods added to Xrm in 2016. You might want to see if it's possible to use [setCurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932126.aspx#BKMK_ViewSelector).

Comment: I called debugger with the snippet that you provided it seems that subgrid loaded before reaching to SetParameter. **orderSubgrid = div#orderssubgrid.ms-crm-ListControl-Ex-Lite** is what I've in debugger

Comment: Then there should be no issue? If the subgrid is loaded before reaching `orderSubgrid.control.SetParameter()` then you shouldn't receive the error **cannot read property 'SetParameter' of undefined**. If there is an issue, you could instead check that you have the `control` property defined too: `if (orderSubgrid.control != null)`

Comment: That is what I don't found in debugger